# Checkbox value in same row diffrent columns php

Tags: php, mysql, post

idont know how to smooth the code out really and if one of the boxes isnt check i will get an error like Undefined $databas(number) and i have to add more than 10 atleast checkboxes and this code isnt an option for that really, i would use databas for name just but i dont know how to make it into same row and for each $data a new column

this is my table i havent include the connect part becouse its not relevant

```
id   url   dok_typ  data1  data2  data3 data4
--- ------ ------------------------------------
 |       |       |      |       |      |
 |       |       |      |       |      |
 |       |       |      |       |      |
```

Html

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="databas1" value="data1" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="databas2" value="data2" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="databas3" value="data3" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="databas4" value="data4" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

this is the php script

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $databas1=$_POST['databas1'];
 $databas2=$_POST['databas2'];
 $databas3=$_POST['databas3'];
 $databas4=$_POST['databas4'];

 if($databas1=="data1"){ $data1=1; }else{ $data1=0;}
 if($databas2=="data2"){ $data2=1; }else{ $data2=0;}
 if($databas3=="data3"){ $data3=1; }else{ $data3=0;}
 if($databas4=="data4"){ $data4=1; }else{ $data4=0;}

 if($data1 + $data2 + $data3 + $data4== 0){ echo "no box checked"; exit();}

 echo("$data1, $data2, $data3, $data4");
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO upload_where (id, url, dok_typ, data1, data2, data3, data4 )                
 VALUES('', '', '', '".$data1."', '".$data2."', '".$data3."','".$data4."' )") or     

 die(mysql_error()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check boxes are either posted, if they're ticked, or not posted if they're unticked. As such, your code should be along the lines of:

`$databas1 = (isset($_POST['databas1']) ? $_POST['databas1'] : false)`

Comment: You sir, saved me from a huge headache, thanks alot!